# implement push notification in android app

Tags: android, eclipse, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I know there are many question relating this, but i am still helpless here.

I need to implement push notification in an android app.
It requires setting up google play services, when i do that it errors our with

Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536

Proguard and stripping google play services doesnt work out well.

Is there any way to implement push notification without referencing google play services.
I am using Eclipse with ADT. Runtime and SDK is API 22.
Any tutorial for this will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that you have reached the dex limit in android which means your project contains more than maximum number of methods allowed by framework which is the Integer datatype size.

Using the ADT and eclipse solving this problem might not be feasible, Please try porting your project to Android Studio(Gradle) as it provides a way to have support for multidex files.

please refer [this](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html), I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you!. So, is there no way for eclipse to handle this, since the team is using Eclipse for the development?

Comment: Well at the moment it seems there is no official way of doing it with eclipse/ant. I know it is hard to make a switch for the whole team but I would strongly recommend making the switch as the official support for ADT is also about end [link](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/06/an-update-on-eclipse-android-developer.html)